# How do I image the beginning portion of a drive with qemu-img convert? (Similar to using dd count=)

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu, disk-image

I have 500 GB (~475 GiB) SSD that I want to image with qcow2. I plan on following [this example](https://superuser.com/questions/1389103/windows-10-uefi-physical-to-kvm-libvirt-virtual) on moving the Windows installation to a Qemu/KVM VM. I shrunk the ~470 GiB bitlocker root partition to 115 GiB [using dislocker and gparted](https://superuser.com/questions/1458673/how-can-i-resize-a-windows-bitlocker-partition-with-gparted). I then moved the 2000 MiB WinRE_DRV partition to the left, leaving no space with itself and the recently shrunk bitlocker partition. In the current situation, the first 116 GiB of the drive contains data, and the rest of it is unallocated space.

I want to image the beginning 116 GiB of data, and exclude the unallocated space to not waste space in the image. At first, I thought of using dd with bs=1M and count=116688, so only the data I want would be copied, and pipping that to qemu-img. However, I later learned that qemu-img [doesn't support stdin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536404/qemu-img-compress-image-from-stdin-gunzip). The suggested solution to that problem was to use nbdcopy, which doesn't work well for me because

> The catch is unfortunately you have to know the size of the final qcow2 file before you start, although it's OK to use a larger size.

This wouldn't work well for me, because I'm going to use compression while making the image, which means that I won't know the final size beforehand. I could just choose a size as big as the uncompressed data (116 GiB) to guarantee it to fit in the image, however doing so would end up wasting space leading it to be an unfavorable solution.

I also tried reading the manpage for qemu-img, and there didn't seem to be any count= option for qemu-img convert, however there did seem to be one for qemu-img dd, which I think wouldn't be helpful in this case.

My original command:

```
dd bs=1M if=/dev/nvme0n1 count=116688 status=progress | qemu-img convert -p -f raw -O qcow2 -c -o compression_type=zstd,preallocation=off /media/user/drive/win11_image.qcow2
```

Comment: Does it work by splitting the operation in 2 commands like : `dd bs=1M if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=disk.raw count=116688 status=progress`, then use : `qemu-img convert -p -f raw -O qcow2 -c -o compression_type=zstd,preallocation=off disk.raw /media/user/drive/win11_image.qcow2` ? - However by doing this, you may have problem with partitions table, you need to check if the `qcow2` is readable and usable.

Comment: @hidigouri I think that your solution would work, however it would require 116 GiB of scratch space where the dd image would be stored. This would be doable, but would probably be slower than doing it with 1 operation. I'll try this if there are no better options. I was also curious about your concern with the partition table, as I heard that dd copies all data on a drive, including partition tables. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Indeed, you will need the double of space, but  I do not see another solution on my side. You right, `dd` will copy the whole data of the drive, including the partitions table if your drive is using `MBR`. If you are using it, the whole partitions tables will be copied (**512 first bytes** of the drive), but if you had several partitions, it will not match with your `qcow2` image as you will copy only first the **116 GiB**, the size describe in the `MBR` sector of the partition may also be not the same.

Comment: You may have the same issue with `GPT`. However, `GPT` partitions table is also located **at the end** of the drive. If you are using `GPT`, the secondary GPT header **will not** be copied with your method. - My opinion is that it's never a good idea to copy a part of a drive to get a `qcow2`.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the information. I ended up using another 128 GB USB drive for the dd output. I'm just waiting to see if It'll work in a VM, but I need to update my computers OS to see, because the older version of Qemu has the error unsupported compression when used with zstd 3 qcow2 images. A newer OS should have a more up to date version of Qemu.